How to implement an "Apple or Orange but not both" constraint
A database schema design question:
Suppose I want to design a database with Robots, Technicians and Sites.
I want to use my database constraints to limit the data to prevent entering some nonsensical cases.
For example, I manufacture a Robot; when I lease him out, I assign and ship him to a Site.
I enter a record in my database - a Robot can only be at one Site, so I could give the Robots table a nullable SiteID Foriegn Key field to Sites to represent that limit.  No robot can then be assigned to two Sites in the database.
create table Sites (
SiteID int not null,
Name varchar(1024) not null,
primary key (SiteID)
);

create table Robots (
RobotID int not null,
SiteID int nullable,
primary key (RobotID),
constraint 'fk_robots_sites_siteid' foreign key (SiteID) references Sites(SiteID)
);

Good so far.
So now I want to add Technicians to my database:
create table Technicians (
TechnicianID int not null,
name varchar(1024) not null,
primary key (TechnicianID)
);

What if... I wanted to have some of my Robots act as a chauffeur to my Technicians?
Then a Robot could be assigned to either a Site or to a Technician - but not both.
I can't figure out how to implement this constraint in the schema.
Suggestions?


either a Site or to a Technician - but not both.

alter table Robots add Check (SiteID is null or TechnicianID is null)


Thanks.  I'll tinker with it but it looks portable to MySQL and MS SQL - perfect.
